# get transformable bounding box in sfml

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

I got an `sf::text` object in `c++ sfml`, `sf::text` is inheriting from `Drawable` and `Transformable`. I want to get the bounding box of that text object so I could see if the mouse is above the text widget but I can't find anything that helps me with that in `Transfomable` or `Drawable`

Comment: `sf::Text::getLocalBounds()`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz thank you but is there a way to do it on `Transformable` and not Text only?

Answer (score 0):

`Drawable` is only about drawing. Actually, it's only the virtual `draw` function. Likewise, `Transformable` is only about transforms (offset, scale, rotation). At its  core it's a 3x3 matrix. Hence it knows nothing about *extents*.

So, the answer to your question is: There is nothing in `Drawable` or `Transformable` that can get you the bounding box you need. You have to access the object directly.